# Single Sign on between client and server in untrusted AD domains

Tags: windows, sql-server, active-directory, single-sign-on

A customer of mine is migrating some serveres to a provider, which will cause (temporarily) clients and servers to be in separate, untrusted AD domains. The application in question is a SQL Backend / Access Client application which uses trusted connections between the Access app on the client and the sql server.

My question is: Is there any way to get some kind of single-sign on to work here, so that users avoid having to enter usernames/passwords when using the app?

Answer (score 1):

I may be naive, but if you got this to work as stated, it would pretty much invalidate the entire purpose of Active Directory.  You should be able to safely let your customer know that you are happily not able to circumvent domain security.

If you could create a temporary trust, you'd be back be in business.  Or if you could keep a DC local until communication is established with the new location.